# Writing deadlines

Tags: commas, capitalization, abbreviations, time, dates

I'm currently using the following date format for setting deadlines:

> Monday, 27 January 2014, 3 PM

My questions are:

- Should I mention time at the beginning or leave it at the end?
- Should I keep the commas?
- Should I write *a.m.* instead of *AM*?

Comment: This depends on what country you live in.

Comment: 12 AM (or 12 a.m.) can be ambiguous. If you mean midday, write '12 noon'.

Comment: I know. We lean more towards BrE here in UAE.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a pure matter of style. Consult your favourite stylebook, but no one form is "better than the others".

Comment: Of course, if you mean 12:00am (and not 12:00pm), you probably mean "12 midnight" and not "12 noon", which is precisely why Barrie is suggesting you specify.  The Europeans (and some others) will express the midnight hour as 0:00 in some travel- and regulations-related contexts, but I don't know whether that's merely a custom or an actual rule.

Comment: Why are you guys talking about 12 AM being confusing or not. I was never concerned about it! Besides, no one has answered my three questions yet.

Comment: I would start with the smallest time unit and then progress from there: 3 [PM/p.m./pm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Abbreviations), Monday, 27 January 2014.

Answer (score -1):

I would say put time at the end,keep the commas and write 3 pm or 3 p.m instead of PM.